# FreeMarker and JSP 2 tag files

Tags: java, jsp, freemarker, taglib

I'm trying to use JSP 2 tags within a FreeMarker (2.3.19) template. In order to do that, I need to convert the following JSP 2 line:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="pagestudio" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

into a FreeMarker supported code line. I've tried with the following:

```
<#assign pagestudio=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/tlds/pagestudio.tld"]>
```

but I need a workaround that allows me to include the tag files instead of the tld.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, FreeMarker doesn't support `.tag` files, only traditional taglibs.